# Azure Access Token - Invalid Signature in Jwt.io

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, jwt

It has been a nightmare. I'm facing problems to verify Azure Access Token Signature using jwt.io. Doesn't matter what I do, the answer is always an invalid signature.

Could someone try to help with this, please?

My Steps:

1. I generated a Token Id and Access Token from the MSAL Java App Example (msal-java-webapp-sample).
2. I get from my Azure Access Token the "kid" from the Access Token header accessing the `jwt.io`.
3. I access the `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"`
4. I open the link "jwks_uri" access from step 3. `"https://login.microsofto…f143/discovery/v2.0/keys"`
5. I get the kid from step 2 and I find it in the `"https://login.microsofto…f143/discovery/v2.0/keys"`.
6. I copy the "x5c" inside the URL described in step 5.
7. I open the jwt.io.
8. I copy the Access Token retrieved from step 2 and copy it in the Encoded Field.
9. I copy the "x5c" attribute retrieved from step 6 in the first field regarding the Signature. (Layout-1)

----- Layout-1 ----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
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
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

But the result is always the same. Invalid Signature.

In my application I am using this URls.

```
Request Azure Code Auth
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_Id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxx12312xxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8443/<AppName>/secure/aad
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid+profile+offline_access
&state=12345
&prompt=login

---- response ---
localhost:8443/msal4jsample/secure/aad?
code=0.AAAAe7KHdX9Z7oIAA
&amp;state=12345
&amp;session_state=716c6fa7-8b51-4025-98ef-489c3b25ab3d#
```

Request Azure Tokens

Post Method

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?
grant_type=authorization_code
&code=<Received from above azure code auth request>
&client_id=<Application_Id Registered in Azure>
&client_secret=<Secret Key>
&scope=openid profile email User.Read
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8443/<MyApp>/secure/aad


---- Response ----

{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "openid profile User.Read email",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "X1YmQ",
    "refresh_token": "PC6YMqqLpvm",
    "id_token": "Y86JentfTUzBQoiUzav3pAu3GIG3OhslQ"
}
```

Why when I try to check the "refresh_token": "PC6YMqqLpvm" in [www.jwt.io](http://www.jwt.io) the Signature is invalid.

Please, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to indicate Azure to sign the Access Token?

Note: I've used this tutorial to check the Signature of Access Token.
https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/03/using-jwt-io-to-verify-the-signature-of-a-jwt-token/

Kind Regards,
Mario Rodrigues

Comment: Is the token an MS Graph API token? If yes, they are special and you can't validate them. You shouldn't be validating their tokens any way, only tokens meant for your app.

Comment: Hi @juunas, in my case I am not using MS Graph API. I am using the MSAL App example to generate the token and MS web page as a reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are requesting an access token for MS Graph API as specified by the scope parameter: `scope=openid profile email User.Read`. User.Read is an MS Graph API scope.

Those tokens are special and you shouldn't be validating them.
It isn't your app's job to validate other APIs' tokens any way.
Refresh tokens are similar in that your app can't validate them.
They only mean something to the identity provider.

The only tokens you should be validating are tokens where the audience (aud) is your app's client id or app id URI.

Comment: Hi @junnas, first of all, many thanks for your help. I really appreciate that. To sum up, I cannot validate Access_Token's Signature that comes from any Microsoft API and Refresh Token. The only signature that I can validate is the ID Token where contains the Audience in the Token Id. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, the Id token and any access tokens that you acquire for your APIs.