# Validate Azure AD access token with spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-spring-cloud

What is the easiest way to switch from jsession based authentication to a token based authentication with Azure AD and Spring security? The documentation is not clear on other approaches to authenticate with azure AD other than the default session based one.

I am trying to see how can I validate the jwt access token using azure AD. The default implementation works with session based authentication (which will not work in a system with multiple instances.) The session-stateless property mentioned in the doc doesn't seem to have any effect on the authentication.

Comment: You can't validate AD tokens issued by MS Graph unfortunately. I tried for a while and saw this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/65172084/319826. I ended up using Azure API gateway. This can validate an AD-token on your behalf. So I use it as a frontend to my backend-service.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Cloud Azure](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-azure) integrate Spring Security with Azure Active Directory.

You could use `spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory` starter to integrate with Spring Security, please refer this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory/web-client-access-resource-server/aad-resource-server) to see how to use it.

For further reading, please refer the [Azure Active Directory dev guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide), it covers these scenarios for you:

- Access a web application
- Access resource servers from a web application
- Protect a resource server/API
- Access other resource servers from a resource server
- Web application and resource server in one application